# Doxygen latex misinterpreting preprocessor definition

Tags: pdf, latex, doxygen, documentation-generation, preprocessor-directive

Ok let me try this again on SO instead of Tex.

So I'm trying to create some PDF's using Doxygen.

I've installed MiKTeX on my Windows 7 box and have managed to get all the Styles needed to get Doxygen to generate a PDF.

Problem is it never resolves 1 cross-reference no matter how many times I re run. (The first re-run tends to get everything but this)

The cross-reference is a Class that looks like this.

```
/*!
 * @class CLASSESREALNAME CLASSESREALNAME.h "CLASSESREALNAME.h"
 * @brief Brief description of CLASSESREALNAME 
 */
class __declspec (dllexport) CLASSESREALNAME { 

//Stuff

}
```

I've configured my template to read '/*!' as Doxygen comments and '@' or '\' are both valid escape characters according to Doxygens Documentation [Here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html).

I found [this](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html) section that helped remove the error when generating HTML but it appears that the latex .tex files don't have the right references in them to resolve this class. I assume it has to do with the `__declspec (dllexport)` because it's the only class I'm documenting with it and it's the only one causing problems.

Is this a bug in Doxygen?

Or more likely do I need to define or do something to make this resolve as expected?

Thanks ahead of time.

Note:

I've also noticed that ALL the file references are '??' and not in the pdf. I'm guessing because this class bombs out everything after it isn't generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was related to defining `\documentclass`,`\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in a `\LaTeXonly` section in a comment somewhere else in the code.

Doxygen **HATED** that. Or more accurately the way MiKTeX reads the file or Doxygen makes the file does not allow for those labels.

So this error turned out to be caused by problems somewhere else but I had no indication of that everything pointed to this class in the log.